# Call to undefined method Vender\Package\Auth::extend() in package

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-package

I'm trying to create an authentication package (module) using `jwt-auth` that can be reused across all of my applications. But I receive errors.

```
Framework   Laravel
Framework version   8.46.0
jwt-auth version    ^1.0.0-beta.3@dev
PHP version 7.4.20
```

Steps to reproduce

- Create a fresh laravel project
- Create a fresh package inside it
- Add `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0.0-beta.3@dev"`, as requirement to the `composer.json` of the package
- Implement `JWTSubject` in your User model
- Try to run any artisan command.

I receive this error:

```
 Error 

  Call to undefined method Vendor\Package\Auth::extend()

  at vendor/tymon/jwt-auth/src/Providers/AbstractServiceProvider.php:98
     94▕      * @return void
     95▕      */
     96▕     protected function extendAuthGuard()
     97▕     {
  ➜  98▕         $this->app['auth']->extend('jwt', function ($app, $name, array $config) {
     99▕             $guard = new JWTGuard(
    100▕                 $app['tymon.jwt'],
    101▕                 $app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider']),
    102▕                 $app['request']

      +8 vendor frames 
  9   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()

      +5 vendor frames 
  15  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

My package name is also `Auth`. I'm stuck at solving this problem. Any help?

Comment: can you show code in package where you used Auth::extend. show full code

Comment: @JohnLobo, that's not my code at all. I have not written one line of code yet. That's the code of the `jwt-auth` package.